# Help with renormalization in $k $ space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, fourier-analysis

I encountered this equation and I am really confused,
$$\exp\big[-H'[\phi']\big]=\left[\int \Pi_{\Lambda/b \leq k \leq \Lambda} d\phi (**k**)\exp\big[-H[\phi]\big]\right]_{k=k'/b, \phi(k)=c \phi'(k')}$$

I can't really describe my issue as I am still trying to understand renormalization but I will try my best to define my confusion,

1. Why can we only integrate one side but shouldn't it be both sides? Both sides used the exponential of the Hamiltonian except that they are at different scales.
2. The Hamiltonian H' is related to $k\leq\Lambda/b$ as seen by this equation, $H'=\int_{k\leq \Lambda/b}...d^dk$. I don't get how does the first equation make sense as it seems to describe the lowest wavenumber band $k\leq \Lambda/b$ with that from the outer wavenumber shell $\Lambda/b \leq k \leq \Lambda$?

I just check wikipedia and my questions and equations are similar to that under the Wilson ERGE where these equations are used instead,
$${\displaystyle Z=\int _{p^{2}\leq \Lambda ^{2}}{\mathcal {D}}\phi \exp \left[-S_{\Lambda }[\phi ]\right].}$$
$${\displaystyle \exp \left(-S_{\Lambda '}[\phi ]\right)\ {\stackrel {\mathrm {def} }{=}}\ \int _{\Lambda '\leq p\leq \Lambda }{\mathcal {D}}\phi \exp \left[-S_{\Lambda }[\phi ]\right].}$$
$${\displaystyle Z=\int _{p^{2}\leq {\Lambda '}^{2}}{\mathcal {D}}\phi \exp \left[-S_{\Lambda '}[\phi ]\right].}$$
So from the above equations, I can re write as
$$\int _{p^{2}\leq \Lambda ^{2}}{\mathcal {D}}\phi \exp \left[-S_{\Lambda }[\phi ]\right]=\int _{p^{2}\leq {\Lambda '}^{2}} {\mathcal {D}}\phi \int _{\Lambda '\leq p\leq \Lambda }{\mathcal {D}}\phi \exp \left[-S_{\Lambda }[\phi ]\right].$$
I don't understand the above equivalence. When I integrate $\int _{\Lambda '\leq p\leq \Lambda }{\mathcal {D}}\phi \exp \left[-S_{\Lambda }[\phi ]\right]$, does it mean that ${\displaystyle \exp \left(-S_{\Lambda '}[\phi ]\right)}$ is just left with $\phi(p)$ whose p only varies in the low wavenumber band, $ p \leq \Lambda'$?